# Check if string contains element in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Rails and learning ActiveRecord and I came across a vexing problem. Here's an array in my model:

```
@sea_countries = ['Singapore','Malaysia','Indonesia', 'Vietnam', 'Philippines', 'Thailand']
```

And here's my ActiveRecord object:

```
@sea_funding = StartupFunding.joins(:startup)
                             .where('startups.locations LIKE ?', '%Singapore%')
```

What I'm trying to do is to return a result where a string in the 'locations' column matches any element in the Array. I'm able to match the strings to each element of an Array (as above), but I'm not sure how to iterate over the whole Array such that the element is included as long as there's one match.

The intent is that an element with multiple locations 'Singapore,Malaysia' would be included within @sea_funding as well.

Well, don't ask me why 'locations' is set as a string. It's just the way the previous developer did it.

Answer (score 1):

You use an IN clause in your `.where` filter:

```
@sea_funding = StartupFunding.joins(:startup)
                             .where(["startups.locations IN (?)", @sea_countries])
```

Answer (score 0):

`@sea_countries.include?(startups.locations)`

This will return a boolean TRUE if the value of the locations column in startups can be found in the sea_countries array, false if it is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
first = true
where_clause = nil

sea_countries.each do |country|
  quoted_country = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_string(country)
  if first
     where_clause = "startups.locations LIKE '%#{quoted_country}%' "
     first = false
  else
     where_clause += "OR startups.locations LIKE '%#{quoted_country}%' "
  end
end

@sea_funding = StartupFunding.joins(:startup)
                             .where(where_clause)
```